# Error in array(c(fruits, cost), dim = c(3, 2, 1), dimnames = list(shop_name, : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, data-structures, compiler-errors, syntax-error, custom-data-type

```
fruits = c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Grapes')

cost = c(20,10,30)
  
shop_name = c("Fruits guy", "Champa seller', "Bad mango"")

price = c("cost of fruits")

market_name = c("Jhoom Market")
  
  
shops_info = array(c(fruits, cost), dim=c(3,2,1), dimnames=list(shop_name, price, market_name)) 
  
print(shops_info)
```

Comment: Please format your question with [community guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your second dimension is of size two. However, the name of the dimension `price`has only one entry. R is expecting it to have 2 entries. This would work:

```
fruits = c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Grapes')
cost = c(20,10,30)

shop_name = c("Fruits guy", "Champa seller", "Bad mango")
price = c("cost of fruits", "Entry needed") #adding fictional name
market_name = c("Jhoom Market")


shops_info = array(c(fruits, cost), dim=c(3,2,1), dimnames=list(shop_name, price, market_name)) 

print(shops_info)
, , Jhoom Market

              cost of fruits Entry needed
Fruits guy    "Apple"        "20"        
Champa seller "Banana"       "10"        
Bad mango     "Grapes"       "30"
```